# can you create and delete files that begin with "-"?

Tags: unix

I a, trying to create a file that begins with the symbol "-" but Unix wont let me do it. I also need to delete one but figured that if i can get one to create then I could use the same method to  delete them. I have tried using double quotes and single quotes

How would you create and then delete a file that begins with the symbol -?

Comment: More suited to [unix.se] instead, as it's an OS question and not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming command line here).

Indeed the shell will assume that strings on the command line starting with `-` are parameters, which are bound to not be valid.

Luckily you can explicitly tell the shell that all parameters are given and that the rest of the line are arguments, with `--`:

```
touch -- -hello
rm -- -hello
```

Comment: The shell does not assume strings that begin with `-` are parameters.  The shell passes those arguments through to the executable just like any other string.  It is up to the command to parse the arguments.